# What formula should I use to pull data from multiple cells in a column, to another column if values meet multiple criteria?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to pull data into one cell from multiple cells. I only want to include data from specific cells in the row, and check other 2 cells if they meet my conditions. In the example below, I want to include values from the column B to the Cell E4, only if there is "BG" prefix in the column A, and a value is added in the column C.

Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/0KwXL1r/Example.jpg

Please refer to the image for the expected results - see Cell E4, this is what I need to get.

Comment: If you have Office 365 Excel then use TEXTJOIN, if not then it will probably need VBA or helper columns.  Look at the questions that are tagged TEXTJOIN and you will find many answers to like questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, seems like TEXTJOIN is not included in my version

Comment: Then use a helper column concatenating the string with the one below if there is a number, then at the top will be your string.  Try that as you are waiting for someone to do it for you.

Comment: I'd if I knew what it means.

Answer (score 0):

In cell D4 I placed the text "bg" as the search term, which is referenced in the formula below.

In cell E4:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A4)),C4>0),B4&" / ","")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A5)),C5>0),B5&" / ","")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A6)),C6>0),B6&" / ","")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A7)),C7>0),B7&" / ","")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A8)),C8>0),B8&" / ","")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A11)),C11>0),B11&" / ","")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,A12)),C12>0),B12&" / ","")
```